# Custom folding for filetype best practice

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, folding

In order to keep my tex files organized, i decided to add the following line to my `.vimrc`, so i can create folds for different parts of them easily by adding "%%" and "%;" as delimiters for them:

```
augroup tex
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *.tex :setfiletype tex
  autocmd BufEnter *.tex :set foldmethod=marker
  autocmd BufEnter *.tex :set foldmarker=%%,%;
augroup END
```

However, if i am editing a tex file and then open another file, regardless of the filetype, these settings continue in effect, which makes me suspect this is bad practice. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps use `:setlocal` instead of `set` to set this option just for the buffer where the tex file is?

Comment: Yes, prefer `:setlocal`. Have a look at filetype plugins; _e.g._, most of what you have can be achieved with `:filetype plugin on` and `setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker=%%,%;` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, prefer `:setlocal`.

Have a look at filetype plugins; *e.g.*, most of what you have can be achieved with `:filetype plugin on` and `setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker=%%,%;` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` (don't forget to update `b:undo_ftplugin`).